# How to properly manage multithreading read and write access in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I'm kind of confused by `Arc` and `Mutex` in rust. My problem is the following:
The program should use `n+1` threads, where only 1 thread has write access to `data` and the other `n` threads can only read `data`. How can I achieve this in rust?

Comment: You can wrap the data in `Arc<Mutex>`? I don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: Of course it may be more efficient to use `RwLock`.

Comment: I guess you still want to do the locking, is you question about how to limit the access to read-only for `n` threads?
The rest is explained pretty well in The Rust Book: https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch16-03-shared-state.html

Comment: My issue is that the threads that only read the data should not lock it, only that thread which writes it. Am I correct?

Comment: What if they want to read while the other thread is writing? They do need to lock. The only thing that is different from `Mutex` is that multiple readers can use the data concurrently, and that is exactly what `RwLock` provides.

Comment: @dnnagy: The threads that need to read the data need to lock it too -- with a `Mutex` or `RwLock` -- in order to get a consistent snapshot. If they did not lock it, they could read a half-overwritten state (half old, half new) which would be nonsensical. So, are you asking about preventing the reader threads to accidentally write, or for patterns that have lower contention for reader threads?

Comment: @MatthieuM. `RwLock` was what i wanted: I wanted to allow multiple reading threads to read at the same time, but allow only the writer thread to write. Of course, as you said, I want data consistency, so nobody should read until writing is done. But different readers should not block each other from reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). With it, readers don't block each other (but writers still block readers and readers block writers).